# Why Optional continue saying that my List in empty?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a Java program that manage a booking ticket system.

I have a film Class:

```
    public class Film {

  private String title;
  private Double price;
  private String ageRestriction;
  private double rating;
  private String genre;
  private String location;
  private String screenDay;
```

A FilmList Class that create an ArrayList of Films item and sort, based by two parameters (Location and Week)

```
    public class FilmList {

    public FilmList(ArrayList<Film> filmArrayList) {
    this.filmArrayList = filmArrayList;
  }

  public FilmList (){
    this.filmArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  public ArrayList <Film> filmArrayList;

  public void addFilm(Film films){
    this.filmArrayList.add(films);
  }

  private String showLocation;
  private String screenWeek;

  public void setScreenWeek(String screenDay) {
    this.screenWeek = screenDay;
  }
  public String getScreenWeek() {
    return screenWeek;
  }
  public void setShowLocation(String location) {
    this.showLocation = showLocation;
  }
  public String getShowLocation() {
    return showLocation;
  }


  public Optional<Film> searchFilm(){
    Optional<Film> movieFounded = filmArrayList.stream().filter(i -> i.getLocation().contains(getShowLocation()) &&
            i.getScreenDay().contains(getScreenWeek())).findAny();
    return movieFounded;
  }
```

The setShowLocation parameter it's stetted by the click of a button (there's one of them for each theatre, and the setScreenWeek it's stetted by a Combobox

the Graphic unit interface with the console. Notice that if I press the button without select anything on the combobox I got an error.

Comment: First create an object of Film then pass that object to filmList.addFilm(film)

Comment: can you please add the exact input which you are using. by looking at output it seems that either your film list is empty or there is something wrong with your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

```
FilmList filmList = new FilmList();
filmList.addFilm
System.out.println(searchFilm().toString());
```

Your code is a bit strange, but I suppose you meant passing a `Film` instance to `addFilm`, and then using `filmList.searchFilm()`.

Anyway

```
filter(
    i -> i.getLocation().contains(getShowLocation()) &&
         i.getScreenDay().contains(getScreenWeek())
)
```

Here you're filtering the `filmArrayList`, which contains a **single element** at that point. And

```
i.getLocation().contains(getShowLocation())
```

means basically

```
i.getLocation().contains(null)
```

as the `showLocation` field isn't initialized.
The same applies for the second condition, using `screenWeek`.

**I'm actually surprised it doesn't throw a** `NullPointerException`, as

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
    return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;  // NullPointerException at s.toString()
}
```

But anyway, let's say you initialized those fields, then the only element is discarded by the `filter` operation, that's why you see `Optional.empty`.

---

```
final FilmList filmList = new FilmList();
filmList.setShowLocation("Your location");
filmList.setScreenWeek("Screen week");
filmList.addFilm(filmInstance);

System.out.println(filmList.searchFilm().toString());
```

You obviosly need a fully constructed `Film` instance

```
final Film filmInstance = new Film(); 
filmInstance.title = "The NullPointerException adventure";
filmInstance.price = 12D;
filmInstance.ageRestriction = "+18";
filmInstance.rating = 18D;
filmInstance.genre = "Horror";
filmInstance.location = "US";
filmInstance.screenDay = "Monday";

filmList.addFilm(filmInstance);
```

---

The problem is in the `FilmList#setShowLocation` method.
You're assigning `showLocation` to itself, and the `location` parameter is unused.

```
public void setShowLocation(String location) {
    this.showLocation = showLocation;
}
```

This should be

```
public void setShowLocation(String location) {
    this.showLocation = location;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188925/discussion-on-answer-by-lppedd-why-optional-continue-saying-that-my-list-in-empt).